# Get the file and line being called on php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
//lets say one of these files have the function test();
include 'a.php';
include 'b.php';
include 'c.php';
include 'd.php';

test();
?>
```

How can I find out which file and line function test() is being called at? (without opening the files)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) :

```
$func = new ReflectionFunction('test');
echo $func->getFileName();
echo $func->getStartLine();
```